# Using the schematics commands in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to use the schematics command "npx ng @spartacus/schematics:add-pwa" (I am not using a global npm repo or angular installation, due to version conflicts with other projects).

I get the following output:

```
The specified command ("@spartacus/schematics:add-pwa") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".
Did you mean "analytics"?
```

ng cli commands work fine, also adding @spartacus/schematics worked fine (`npx ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest`), yarn build works fine (`npx yarn build`).

If I run `npx ng add @spartacus/schematics --ssr`, this also works fine, prompts me again for the features I want and adds SSR to the project.

Do I have to do anything else to be able to run the additional Spartacus Schematics commands as they are mentioned in the documentation (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/schematics/#additional-commands-for-core-libraries-and-features)?

Thank you!
Cristi C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was a mistake on my side. I was trying to call:

```
npx ng @spartacus/schematics:add-pwa
```

but the correct call is:

```
npx ng g @spartacus/schematics:add-pwa
```

Reading the documentation with more attention helps...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run `npx ng add @spartacus/schematics --pwa`?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. But it is not what I am looking for, I was looking to call "npx ng @spartacus/schematics:add-pwa".